# CSS background shadow on div acts different to adjacent div

Tags: html, css

So I have these two divs sitting next to each other inline

http://jsfiddle.net/A5Jc7/60/

html:

```
<div>
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.box1 {
    width:200px;
    min-height:200px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
}
.box1:hover {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888888;
    height:200px;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
}
.box2 {
    width:200px;
    min-height:200px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
}
.box2:hover {
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888888;
    height:200px;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
}
```

I hover over the left div and I get a shadow which is UNDER the right div. I hover over the right div and the shadow is OVER the left div. Why does it act like this? I want the shadows to be identical. I tried z-index tricks but that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm looking at this in Chrome and the box shadows are identical. What browser are you using to see this discrepancy?

Comment: Are you expecting the shadows to be above or below the divs?

Comment: regardless of over or below... the reason your shadows show differently is do to the flow of the html... think of it as though every element stacks upwards from left to right. You only need to use a z-index when you want to counter act the natural flow. As noted however, z-index only works when positioned (absolute,relative or fixed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Z-index only works for elements that are absolutely or relatively positioned.

Subsequently, add the following to each box:

```
position:relative;
```

And the following to the hovers:

```
z-index:1;
```

If you want the shadows to be behind the parent of the object, just use:

```
z-index:-1;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/A5Jc7/64/

This way, you don't need to use odd z-indexes, or absolute position the boxes which requires even more CSS to style correctly.

Comment: Both shadows are above the DIVs @Charlie, which exactly opposite to what he wants.

Comment: He didn't say whether or not he wanted it above the div. He just said he wanted them to be the same.

Comment: aren't shadows supposed be behind the object anyways?

Comment: The shadows are behind the object. If you want to have the shadows be behind the parent of the object, you can just change the `z-index` to `-1`.

Comment: Cheers Charlie that works well, you supplied first working answer with the cleanest code, you get the tick ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/A5Jc7/65/

```
.box1{
    width:200px;
    min-height:200px;
    background:black;
    float:left;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    z-index: 1; 
    position: relative;
}

.box1:hover{
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888888;    
    height:200px;
    margin:20px 0 0 0;
    z-index:2;
}
```

added positioning and z-index on hover to both items.

Comment: this is not cross browser compatible.

Comment: which browser? obviously I didn't test my quick response on every browser available, or was this simply because I forgot to set a base z-index?

Comment: IE9. Not sure why as the sample in the code looks different from fiddle. I just checked the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Because the offset of your shadow cover the first block,

If you edit the x position in the second box shadow like`box-shadow: 5px 0px 5px 5px #888888;` you are done.

But if you want to keep the simmetry you have to change the first shadow offset also `box-shadow: -5px 0px 5px 5px #888888;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning to make the z-index work properly.

```
.box0 {
position:relative;
width:400px;
height:200px; 
}

.box1{
width:200px;
min-height:200px;
background:black;
position:absolute;
margin:20px 0 0 0;
z-index: 1;
left:0;
 top:0       
}

.box1:hover{
background: white;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888888;    
height:200px;
margin:20px 0 0 0;
    z-index:5
}

.box2{
width:200px;
min-height:200px;
background:black;
position:absolute;
margin:20px 0 0 0;
z-index:1
z-index: 1;
right:0;
 top:0           
}

.box2:hover{
background: white;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888888;  
height:200px;
margin:20px 0 0 0;
    z-index:5
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `z-index: -1` for **.box1** and `z-index: -11` for **.box2:hover**

Also use `position:relative` for both boxes as you need the position with z-index property.

like this:

```
.box1{
width:200px;
min-height:200px;
background:black;
float:left;
margin:20px 0 0 0;   
width: 200px;
z-index: -1;
position: relative;
}

.box2:hover{
background: white;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #888888;  
height:200px;
margin:20px 0 0 0;
z-index: -11;
position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A5Jc7/63/

The idea is to push the shadow of box2 during hover below the box1.